# How to add search and mic button in input text?

Tags: html, css, icons

I want to add a search icon on the left side of the input text and a speaker icon on the right side.

Something like this
[image]

Currently my I have :

[image]

Here is my code :

```css
.search-bar {
  width: 20%;
  position: relative;
}

.search-bar input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 18px;
  outline: none;
}

.search-ico {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!--Search Bar-->
<div class="search-bar">
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search" />
  <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass search-ico"></i>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the answer above you can add pointer for the icon for simulate mouse with `cursor:pointer;` like:

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  marging: 0;
}
.search-bar {
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
}

.search-bar input {
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 18px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.search-ico {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top:8px;
  cursor: pointer; // add cursor
}

.microphone-ico {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 8px;
  cursor: pointer; // add cursor
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!--Search Bar-->
<div class="search-bar">
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search" />
  <i class="fa fa-search search-ico"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-microphone microphone-ico"></i>
</div>
```

---

If you use bootstrap 4 you can use input group like:

```css
.input-group-text i{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-search search-ico"></i></span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Search here">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-microphone microphone-ico"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going the right way, using `position: absolute` set the icons

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  marging: 0;
}
.search-bar {
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
}

.search-bar input {
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 18px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.search-ico {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top:8px;
}

.microphone-ico {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!--Search Bar-->
<div class="search-bar">
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search" />
  <i class="fa fa-search search-ico"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-microphone microphone-ico"></i>
</div>
```